# strage uitableview cell behavior: view moves inside cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having some strange uitableview behavior- my customs cells have a little extra space around them that I cannot fix. I can also move the cells in that space. I have attached a couple of pictures as my English is not letting me to explain better. Any ideas on what might the issue be? I can post my code for my custom cell but it even happens with admob add cell, so I am not sure it is related to the custom cell.

EDIT: Added code for heights

EDIT2: I changed the scroll view alloc to

`scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width,self.bounds.size.height)];`

And it fixed the moving of the cell. But that white line is still there.

Table View

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


   // return (self.tableViewHome.bounds.size.height-49-6-self.tableViewHome.tableHeaderView.bounds.size.height-self.tableViewHome.tableFooterView.bounds.size.height-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)/3;
    float height = self.tableViewHome.frame.size.height-self.tableViewHome.tableHeaderView.bounds.size.height-30.0;

    if (indexPath.item==5)
    {
        height=kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.item==1 || indexPath.item==3)
        {
            height=15.0;
        }
        else
        {
        if (indexPath.item==0 || indexPath.item==2 || indexPath.item==4)
        {
        height=(height-kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height)/3;
        }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Height:%f",height);

    return height;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.1;
}
```

Custom Cell

```
-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {

        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];


//        NSInteger viewcount= 3;
//        for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++) {

//        CGFloat x = 2 * self.bounds.size.width;
        todayView = [HomeTodayView homeTodayView];
        todayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
        todayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];




        avgView = [HomeAvgView homeAvgView];
        avgView.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);


           // [[HomeTodayView alloc] initWithFrame:

        todayView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        avgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [scrollView addSubview:todayView];
        [scrollView addSubview:avgView];


        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width *2, self.bounds.size.height+100);
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.bounces = NO;


        [self addSubview:scrollView];



    }
    return self;
}
```

[image: Lowest]

[image: Max]

Comment: Having grouped table view ?

Comment: yes actually. changed it to plain but I don't see any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

[table setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

**NOTE:-** table = your tableview name.

If this does not work then please check that your custom cell height and the row height of tableView are same?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not help. I have added my code for setting the heights, maybe the mistake is there?

Comment: That would have been my suggestion too, so can I just make sure that you're setting that outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath? i.e. That's a setting on the table as a whole, not individual cells.  Maybe do it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Set the separator style in viewDidLoad?